# In chat, how do I search for messages I've posted?

Tags: support, chat

Is there a way that I can search for messages I've posted in chat?  I tried searching for my name, which produced some messages posted by others that mentioned me but didn't produce any of my own messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=&user=25779&room=

Comment: Or http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=&user=17863&room=. You seem to have two accounts on chat.se.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how that happened.

Comment: Weird -- one of those shows the icon for English.SE, which is my highest-rep SE site.  The other shows hermeneutics, and I think I used chat there exactly once.  Meanwhile, my most frequent chat use (and all of it recent) is here.  I clicked the "change" link on one of them but it's been "loading" for a couple minutes.  Is there some way to bring all this together under the J.SE banner?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, beats me. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask? `:-)`

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Asked...